# How to remove a button if there is no more info in the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

The following code is running smoothly, but I want to implement it in a way that when I do a *getNextPers()* and there is no info, it hides/removes the *Ver Mais* button. I've been looking for solutions but have found none, so any help is good. Thank you.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            personagens: [],
            page: 1,
            showBtn: true,
        };
        this.getNextPers = this.getNextPers.bind(this);
    }

    getNextPers(){
        const peopleApiEndpoint = `https://swapi.co/api/people/${this.state.page}`;
        axios.get(peopleApiEndpoint).then((p) =>
            if(p=={}){
                this.setState({ showBtn: false });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({ personagens: this.state.personagens.concat(p), page: this.state.page+1 })
            }
        );
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p><b>Personagens:</b></p>
                {this.state.personagens.map((pers, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <br />
                        <p><i>Name:</i> {pers.data.name}</p>
                        <p><i>Height:</i> {pers.data.height} cm</p>
                        <p><i>Mass:</i> {pers.data.mass} kg</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
                <button onClick={this.getNextPers}>Ver Mais</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is here:

```
axios.get(peopleApiEndpoint).then((p) => {
    if (p == {}) { // THIS WILL NEWER WORK AS EXPECTED
        this.setState({showBtn: false});
    } else {
        this.setState({
            personagens: this.state.personagens.concat(p),
            page: this.state.page + 1
        });
    }
});
```

Also `swapi` return 404 when there is no more results instead of empty object so you need to add `catch` block to your `axios.get` as described in docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

```
axios.get(peopleApiEndpoint).then((p) => {
    this.setState({
        personagens: this.state.personagens.concat(p),
        page: this.state.page + 1
    });

}).catch((err) => {
    this.setState({showBtn: false});
});
```

Now you can use conditional rendering like:

```
{(this.state.showBtn && <button onClick={this.getNextPers}>Ver Mais</button>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing the `showBtn` state in your component, you can use it to conditionally render the button as follows:

```
render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p><b>Personagens:</b></p>
                {this.state.personagens.map((pers, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <br />
                        <p><i>Name:</i> {pers.data.name}</p>
                        <p><i>Height:</i> {pers.data.height} cm</p>
                        <p><i>Mass:</i> {pers.data.mass} kg</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
                { (this.state.showBtn) ?
                    <button onClick={this.getNextPers}>Ver Mais</button>
                    :
                    null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Your `if` is actually literal text.

Comment: Sorry about it ! Just noticed (Duh, me). I have made the changes

Answer (score 0):

First thing `getNextPers` does not return anything and you can achieve  the show/hide by using condintion in your code

```
{ this.your_condition ? 
    <button onClick={this.getNextPers}>Ver Mais</button> : ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Ramya answer you can also use

```
render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p><b>Personagens:</b></p>
                {this.state.personagens.map((pers, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <br />
                        <p><i>Name:</i> {pers.data.name}</p>
                        <p><i>Height:</i> {pers.data.height} cm</p>
                        <p><i>Mass:</i> {pers.data.mass} kg</p>
                    </div>
                ))}

                { this.state.showBtn && <button onClick={this.getNextPers}>Ver Mais</button> }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: this only renders if the first condition returns true.